# Access div element inside iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, scroll

I am trying to create buttons to scroll a div up and down. I have downloaded javascript file called vectordiv.js (from here: http://www.scripterlative.com/files/vectordiv.htm).

The javascript file can be previewed here: http://ozesports.net.au/jscripts/vectordiv.js

I have this working perfectly with a test div. Comments are at the top of the JS file for how to use, but basically you call:

vectorDiv( 'controll element id', 'div id', "direction to scroll" );

I have an iFrame with a src="index.php" for example... inside index.php I have several divs. When I try pass through the name of the div ('currentroom_left') I get a message back from the JS saying

> Element with ID 'currentroom_left' not found. Script must be configured
>   at a point BELOW all involved elements.

My script is below my iframe code and my controlling buttons, however, it seems that this javascript file does not have access to the elements inside the iframe src... All the files are on the same domain, but not in same directories (not sure if that matters).

This is the part of the code where it cannot find my div id:

```
this.$ = function( id )
{
  var elem = document.getElementById( id );

  if( !elem || elem.id !== id )
  {
    elem = null;
    alert( 'Element with ID "' + id + '" not found.\n\nScript must be configured at a point BELOW all involved elements.' );
  }

  return elem;
}
```

I do not plan on using this anywhere else, so I have no issues hardcoding my iFrame id in the JS.. I tried changing this to something like:

```
this.$ = function( id )
{
  var elem = document.getElementById('ozechat_iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById( id );

  alert(elem);

  if (elem == null)
  {
       var elem = document.getElementById( id );
  }

  alert(elem);

  if( !elem || elem.id !== id )
  {
    elem = null;
    alert( 'Element with ID "' + id + '" not found.\n\nScript must be configured at a point BELOW all involved elements.' );
  }

  return elem;
}
```

This seemed to stop the error, but wasnt scrolling the internal div... Any idea?

Comment: Could you show me the output of urs in fiddle..

Comment: I think you can not access the content of iframe directly.

Comment: If you want to find an element inside an iframe, you have to make sure  the iframe has finished loading and then you have to get the document from the iframe and search in that document - it is a different document than the one that contains the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the library you have chosen doesn't work in a cross-frame case.
So what you can do is following:

- implement the same flow inside an iframe
- add a button on the top level which basically clicks button inside an iframe
- hide button inside an iframe

Something like this:
Main:

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('frm').contentWindow.document.getElementById('btn').click()">Scroll</button>
<iframe src="frm.html" id="frm" />
</body>
</html>
```

Iframe:

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="btn" style="display:none">Scroll</button>
<div id="scrlDiv" style="height:100px">
<div style="height:600px">Scroll me</div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='vectordiv.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>      
   vectorDiv( 'btn', 'scrlDiv', "down" );      
</script>
</body>
</html>
```